# Search for a string in a text file and parse that line (Linux, C)

Tags: c, linux, parsing, text-files

This is "how to parse a config file" question.
Basically i have a text file (/etc/myconfig) that has all kind of settings. I need to read that file and search for the string:

```
wants_return=yes
```

once I locate that string I need to parse it and return only whatever it is after the equal sign.
I've tried using a combinations of fgets and strtok but I'm getting confused here.
in any case anyone knows a function that can perform this?

Code is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `fgets()` and `strtok()`? What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: It'd be helpful to provide some example code of what you've done, and an explanation of how it fails to meet your expectation.

Comment: strtok never return the string after the equal sign. I'm not going to post the 100 lines of code here sorry

Comment: A representative portion, or a ~10 line distilled version would suffice.

Comment: Are you open to using an existing library for this?

Comment: What's your second call to the `strtok()` function? And the first too?

Comment: thank you all, but i don't need help debugging my code, I just need an answer, if you know the answer please post it.
This is proprietary code so i can't post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: (note: I'm unsure if fgets is supposed to include the newline character in the returned string; if it isn't, you can drop the check for it)

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned MAXLINE=9999;
char const* FCFG="/etc/myconfig";
char const* findkey="wants_return=";


char * skip_ws(char *line)
{
    return line+strspn(line," \t");
}

char * findval(char *line,char const* prefix,int prelen)
{
    char *p;
    p=skip_ws(line);
    if (strncmp(p,prefix,prelen)==0)
        return p+prelen;
    else
        return NULL;
}

char *findval_slow(char *line,char const* prefix)
{
    return findval(line,prefix,strlen(prefix));
}

int main() {
    FILE *fcfg;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char *p,*pend;
    int findlen;

    findlen=strlen(findkey);

    fcfg=fopen(FCFG,"r");

    while (p=fgets(line,MAXLINE,fcfg)) {
        printf("Looking at %s\n",p);
        if (p=findval(line,findkey,findlen)) {
            pend=p+strlen(p)-1; /* check last char for newline terminator */
            if (*pend=='\n') *pend=0;
            printf("Found %s\n",p); /* process/parse the value */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example using `strtok`:

```
const int linelen = 256;
char line[linelen];

FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
} else {
    while (! feof(fp)) {
        if (fgets(line, linelen , fp)) {
            const char* name = strtok(line, "= \r\n");
            const char* value = strtok(NULL, "= \r\n");
            printf("%s => %s\n", name, value);
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);
}
```

Note, you'll need to put some additional error checking around it, but this works to parse the files I threw at it.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  From the docs "Checks whether the End-of-File indicator associated with stream is set, returning a value different from zero if it is."

Comment: It works in your code, but it doesn't check if the file is at the end. It checks if a previous read attempt failed due to the file ending. Usually there's no `feof()` in code that stops when the file ends. In your code, the `if` fails, the code goes back to the `while`, which fails but is redundant.

Comment: It is usual to have 1 single test: `while(fgets(...)) { work(); }`

Comment: There are other reasons for `fgets()` to return null, not just for the file ending.  My code will continue to loop until it consumes the entire file.  In fact, `feof()` works _just_ as I think it does.

Comment: If it becomes necessary to handle other errors, an `else` can be added to check `ferror()` and handle the error without breaking out of the read loop.  This allows the caller to try to read again if the error is recoverable.

Comment: I think that other kinds of error besides EOF (eg: network down, media removed) do not set `feof()` to return true. If I'm right you may be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Confirm infinite loop on my machine. I tested with a file on a pen-disk and removed the pen-disk mid-way through the loop (I added a `getchar()` in there). Amazingly the program continued correctly to the end of file (file was cached) but entered an infinite loop after the last line.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it looks like you're already getting the appropriate line from the text file using **fgets** and loading it into a character buffer.  You can use **strtok** to parse the tokens from the line.

If you run it with the string *buffer* as the first argument, it will return the first token from that string.  If you run the same command with the first argument set to *NULL* it will return subsequent tokens from the same original string.

A quick example of how to retrieve multiple tokens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[17]="wants_return=yes";
  char* tok;
  tok = strtok(buffer, "=");
  printf("%s\n", tok); /* tok points to "wants_return" */
  tok = strtok(NULL, "=");
  printf("%s\n", tok); /* tok points to "yes" */
  return 0;
}
```

For the second **strtok** call, you can replace the `"="` with `""` to return everything to the end of the string, instead of breaking off at the next equal sign.

Comment: The string comes from `fgets()`: it has a final newline. If you do the second `strtok` with `"\n"` you get all the remaining string **AND** get rid of the newline :)

Answer (score -1):

With a POSIX shell, I'd use something like:

```
answer=`egrep 'wants_config[ ]*=' /etc/myconfig | sed 's/^.*=[ ]*//'`
```

Of course, if you're looking for an answer that uses the C STDIO library, then you really need to review the STDIO documentation.

Comment: C, i need C code. I know how to do that from the command line. and no, i can't use system()